# Generization gives ring map

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme, $x \in X$, and let $\tilde x$ be a generization of $x$. In other words, $x \in \overline{\{\tilde x\}}.$

I am having trouble understanding why this makes $\mathcal{O}_{X,\tilde x}$ an $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$-algebra. Or in other words, how we get a morphism $\mathrm{Spec} \, \mathcal{O}_{X, \tilde x} \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}\, \mathcal{O}_{X,x}.$

It seems that when $X = \mathrm{Spec}\, A$ is affine, $\mathfrak{p} \in \overline{\{\mathfrak{q}\}} = V(\mathfrak{q})$ is the same as saying that $\mathfrak{q} \subseteq \mathfrak{p}$, so we easily get a homomorphism $A_{\mathfrak{p}} \rightarrow A_{\mathfrak{q}}.$ So I'm worried about the case when $x$ and $\tilde x$ don't lie together in an affine open subset.

Comment: If $U$ is any affine open subset containing $x$, does it automatically contain the generization, by definition of closure?

Comment: @Mohan Sorry, I accidentally closed my browser and now that account is gone. No, I don't see why that would be true. After all, if $X$ is any integral scheme, then it has a generic point $\eta$ which is a generization of every $x$. If $X$ is not affine then we can always find a point $x$ that doesn't share an affine neighborhood with $\eta$?

Comment: I think you should review the characterizations of the closure of a set. Every nonempty open of an integral scheme contains the generic point.

Comment: @Hoot You're right, my remark wasn't correct

Answer (score 1):

$\mathcal O_{X,\bar x}$ is an $\mathcal O_{X,x}$-algebra means that we get a ring map $\mathcal O_{X,x} \to \mathcal O_{X,\bar x}$, not the other way around.

Given an open $U \ni x$, we have $\bar x \in U$, hence we get map $\mathcal O_{X}(U) \to \mathcal O_{X,\bar x}$. Taking the direct limit over all such $U$, we get the desired map $\mathcal O_{X,x} \to \mathcal O_{X,\bar x}$.